# Creating 'temporary' memory optimised tables with only read/write roles

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I'm currently trying to get an application to use memory optimised tables instead of temporary tables, but have hit an issue.

The issue is related to permissions, as users of the application are only ever allowed read/write roles.

Currently, the application does the following;

1. Create temporary table on server
2. Bulk write data to temporary table
3. Merge table to main table

(Works fine, as temporary tables can be created by anyone)

What I want the application to do is this;

1. Create memory optimised table on server
2. Bulk write data to memory optimised table
3. Merge (custom merge as MERGE isn't supported) to main table

This fails as the user doesn't have the correct permissions.

Now my question is;

Is there any way I can get this to work, whilst restricting users to read/write roles?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many "temp" tables are needed? If the number isn't huge I'd just keep the memory optimized tables around and truncate them as necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of users will be large, so I have to create the "temp" tables on the fly.

Comment: Can the application call a stored procedure instead of issuing a bunch of ad hoc SQL? If so, you could grant privileges to the procedure, instead of to the user, and then the user just needs execute rights on the procedure.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I've checked, I can do it with a stored procedure, so I've implemented it with that, and it works. I guess the above should still be open, but I'm beginning to believe it isn't possible without a stored procedure. If you make an answer, I can tick it if you like.

Comment: What is the problem with a regular temp?  It is going to be faster than network speed.

Comment: There is an overhead of storing a temporary table, as it will commit it to disk. A schema-only memory optimised table is never committed to disk, and would be faster. That's how I understand it anyway! Correct me if I'm wrong though!